# Probability and understanding solve

Tags: probability

If $P(A) = 2/5$ and $P(B)=1/3$ and $P(A \cup B) = 1/2$, find:

1. $P(A \cap B)$ 
   Well i reasoned that I could make $2/5 + 1/3 = 1/2$
   put them all same denominator like 
   $12/30 +10/30 = 1/2$ which i know would be $15/30 $
   I found that $22/30$ is over half by $7/30$ so that must be my intersection that was counted twice. 
   like the formula $P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) $
2. $P(B|A)$ (Is this read probability of B given A?) 
   So I think I take the intersection of them both that I found in question 1 and divide it by the restricted to A. 
   I found this formula online $P(B∣A):=P(A \cap B)/P(A)$, 
   So I did this: 
   $7/30$ divided by $2/5$ is the same as $7/30 \cdot 5/2 = 35/60 = 7/12$
3. $P(A|B) $
   So I think I do it the same way as above. 
   7/30 divided by $P(B) $
   = $7/30$ divided by $1/3$ is the same as $7/30 \cdot 3/1 = 21/30 = 7/10$
4. Are A and B independent events? 
   I have no idea. 
   when they are separate on my Venn diagram it seems so, when you start saying given I am lost.

I am grateful for any help. 
If you do decide to help, please provide explanations as well. 
thank you

Comment: There is independence if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ so just check that.

Comment: So I checked the independence and I can see that they are NOT independent of each other. 
I did this: 7/30 = 2/5 * 1/3  and it does not work, 2/5 * 1/3 = 2/15. And 2/15 does NOT = 7/30 
Please confirm.

Comment: I confirm that the events are not independent and the method used to find that out is fully legal. Another way to come to this conclusion is the observation that $P(B|A)\neq P(B)$ here. Off course the observation that $P(A|B)\neq P(A)$ is also enough.

Comment: I am very grateful for this site, thank you so much!!! I am learning as fast as I can, but I see my teacher races by so fast and classes are just 50 minutes long, so she is struggling to get through all of the subject, so individual time with her is very rare. Also, Math may not be my strong point, but at least I am willing! I will keep trying and soon I will get it. Thank you once again. Sincerely Barb

Answer (score 3):

Let me take these point by point:

1. Yes, it is true that $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$; I don't like your reasoning for it, since you claimed that two numbers are equal that aren't equal, but you've got basically the right idea.  You can use this to solve for $P(A\cap B)$.
2. Yes, $P(B\mid A)$ is read as the probability of $B$ given $A$, or $B$ *conditioned* on $A$. Your formula is correct.
3. Yes.
4. Let's think about what it means for two events to be independent; there are a few equivalent ways to think about it.  The most common one is that $A$ and $B$ are independent of $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$; which, you can check in this case, is not true.  Another way, more in line with what you've already solved in the problem, is that $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ and vice-versa (provided your events don't have probability $0$).  In other words: they are independent if knowing whether or not one of them happens *doesn't affect the likelihood of the other happening*.

   You can see that this should be the case as a consequence of the first definition; if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then
   $$
   P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)\cdot P(B)}{P(B)}=P(A).
   $$

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind saying that $A$ and $B$ are independent is that the probability of $A$ remains the same, regardless of whether you know that $B$ has occurred.  That is,
$$P(A\,|\,B)=P(A)\ .$$
Using the formula
$$P(A\,|\,B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\ ,$$
this condition can also be written as
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$
which is the definition given in most books.  If you follow this through you can see that it is also the same as
$$P(B\,|\,A)=P(B)\ ,$$
that is, the probability of $B$ remains the same, regardless of whether you know that $A$ has occurred.  (That is, the same as the top of this answer, but with $A$ and $B$ interchanged.  In your problem you can easily calculate $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A)P(B)$ in order to determine whether the events are independent.

Your answers to 1, 2 and 3 are correct.  And yes, it is read "$A$ given $B$".

Comment: I would cut '...whether you know...' here. It is not subjective.

Comment: @drhab, strictly speaking you are right of course.  But I'm not writing a textbook and I feel this is a helpful way to explain it.  I'm going to leave it.